# Python, Is there any way to login to google cloud identity that then connects through SAML to Azure AD?

Tags: python, azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-active-directory, saml

As in the user clicks a link, and instead of being presented with google login page he is presented with azure, however in the backend the server connects through oauth to google cloud identity and then shows the user the SAML login page for Azure.

Below an image that represents what I mean
[image]

Keeping in mind I already have third party SSO enabled, and already tested logging in to google console from Azure AD and it works fine, however when I try to do it programatically by calling google Oauth2 I get the login page from google, then then the login page from Azure and finally an error.

Comment: Edited with clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest following this guide in [Federating Google Cloud with Azure Active Directory: Configuring provisioning and single sign-on](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/federating-gcp-with-azure-ad-configuring-provisioning-and-single-sign-on). The [login process](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/federating-gcp-with-azure-active-directory#mapping_user_accounts) should function similarly to what you detailed.

Comment: Thank you, that's the guide that I followed before, and that's exactly how you do it, however you will always have the Google login window without password which was what I was trying to avoid.

However, this is the correct answer as it's not possible to do it in any other way, so I'll just mark it as correct.